# H. Abels' paper about Specker compactifications

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups, geometric-group-theory

Is there an English translation for Herbert Abels' paper: Specker-Kompaktifizierungen
von lokal kompakten topologischen Gruppen?

Comment: Niels Henrik Abel lived 1802–1829, Ernst Specker 1920–2011.

Comment: Thank you. I've meant Herbert Abels indeed.

Comment: I've worked a lot with this great paper... no translation, I had to struggle with German...

Comment: @YCor, thank you. I've found the information that I was looking for on a recent paper (I guess it's yours).